# Stop share folder except default share, remote IPC and remote admin

Tags: powershell, command-line

All my windows client have a default share folder like this.
C$
D$
IPC$
ADMIN$

but i want delete or stop share folder except that, how can i delete or stop that share folder except default share folder in *Command Line* ?

or maybe there is some script i can use in *powershell*.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: im trying to do this.

net share Users /y /delete
net share Scan/y /delete

that script running into batch files bcause as far as i know most of my windows client always open scan and users folder

Comment: For others to follow and respond to, put your code in your original question, not the comment section. Lastly, those are all default shares created by the OS, not a user. This is the Windows OS operational management 101 kind of thing. Why are you trying to do this? I cannot think of a use case for what you are trying to do. These shares are created and used by the Windows OS, on OS install and drive insertion/adds.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments.

This is not a PowerShell code issue or even cmd.exe. It is a Windows OS config misunderstanding.

As per MS Docs (this talking to WS2K8 but applies to all server and clientside versions):

> How to remove administrative shares in Windows Server 2008
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/remove-administrative-shares
>
> Introduction By default, Windows Server 2008 automatically creates
> special hidden administrative shares that administrators, programs,
> and services can use to manage the computer environment or network.
> These special shared resources aren't visible in Windows Explorer or
> in My Computer. However, you can view them by using the Shared Folders
> tool in Computer Management. Depending on the configuration of your
> computer, some or all of the following special shared resources may be
> listed in the Shares folder in Shared Folders:
>
> DriveLetter$: It's a shared root partition or volume. Shared root
> partitions and volumes are displayed as the drive letter name appended
> with the dollar sign ($). For example, when drive letters C and D are
> shared, they're displayed as C$ and D$.
>
> ADMIN$: It's a resource that is used during remote administration of a
> computer.
>
> IPC$: It's a resource that shares the named pipes that you must have
> for communication between programs. This resource cannot be deleted.
>
> NETLOGON: It's a resource that is used on domain controllers.
>
> SYSVOL: It's a resource that is used on domain controllers.
>
> PRINT$: It's a resource that is used during the remote administration
> of printers.
>
> FAX$: It's a shared folder on a server that is used by fax clients
> during fax transmission.
>
> ***Generally, we recommend that you don't modify these special shared resources***. However, if you want to remove the special shared
> resources and prevent them from being created automatically, you can
> do it by editing the registry.

So, if you choose to do this, you can do it via the registry, using cmd.exe or PowerShell cmdlets. ***Yet, you really need to know the impacts of this if you do.***

Again as per MS...

> ***Generally, we recommend that you don't modify these special shared resources***